# Laravel 4 passing data to @include

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a view called admin.users. In that view I include header and footer using @include directive. I write all my views-including stuff in routes.php, so for admin.users it is:

```
Route::get('users', function() {
    // ...
    return View::make('admin.users')->with('num', $usersNum);
}
```

And in users.blade.php:

```
@include('admin.partials.header')
// ....
@include('admin.partials.footer')
```

Is it possible to pass "users num" to header view in order to show that variable? And is it a good practice the way I'm combining views, because I read about controller layouts but actually I decided to have only rest controllers while I include view only in routes.php (like load static markup and after that communicate with server by ajax)

Comment: Hmm, actually I found that @include('admin.partials.header', array('usersNum' => $num)) works, but I'm not sure if that is a good way since I have found nothing about this feature in docs..

Comment: Question: Why don't you create an `admin.template` view with your header and footer in it, and start your views with `@extends('admin.template')` ? That doesn't solve your problem but is closer to "the laravel way" (tm).

Comment: Thanks. I made 'admin/layout.blade.php', and used composer to pass data to that view!

Comment: Glad it worked, and your code is now much cleaner and "laraveler". I posted my comment as an answer if you want to accept it. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at 'ViewComposers' (http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers). This is a great way to share data with your views and keep your routes file clean.

In global.php (or any other place really) add:

```
View::composer('admin.users', function($view)
{
    // Do your $usersNum logic here
    ...

    $view->with('num', $usersNum);
});
```

If at some point you want this data to be available in admin.dashboard as well, just rewrite to:

```
View::composer(array('admin.users', 'admin.dashboard'), function($view)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment (and what seems to have fixed your issue) you should create an `admin.template` view with your header and footer in it, and start your views with `@extends('admin.template')`.